# Powershell remoting and SPNs

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I'm attempting to configure powershell remoting on a newly built server and am confused about something. Specifically, the WSMan listener is configured to use port 5985, but when I add the SPN http/computername:5985 computername$, it doesn't take, but when I add the SPN http/computername computername$, it does. How do I configure a server (e.g. a web server) that already has the http SPN assigned to a different account?

Comment: I'm confused, why are you trying to register an HTTP SPN? Our WSMan SPNs are as follows `WSMAN/Hostname` and `WSMAN/Hostname.fqdn.example.edu`.

Comment: After getting a failure, there was an error in the error log that specifically said that it tried the http SPN.

Comment: Also, the WSMAN SPNs (both FQDN and hostname) exist.